# Reduce white space below plot area without using negative marginBottom

Tags: highcharts

I want to reduce the area between the plot area and the border without using negative marginBottom because if I use that, the plot area covers up my border( both plotBorder and border), so is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you show your configuration and what white space you'd like to remove?

Comment: Can you set up a live example of the problem? You can try to look through the API for available options - e.g. spacing might be useful in this case http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacing

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following CSS to the box you wish to move:

```
bottom:-100px;
```